# Determine `SObject type` from relationship name without an exhaustive search

Tags: apex, sobject, describesobject, describefieldresult

Consider a general relation `'Foo.Bar'` and some `SObject` type. An example might be `'Account.Id'` and an `Opportunity.SObjectType`.

Can I determine `SObjectType` `Foo` is referring to without getting the field map and checking each `DescribeFieldResult` to find the field where `getRelationshipName() == 'Foo'` and then extracting potential types from `getReferenceTo()`?

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem but one way is to [parse the ID prefix](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000340200&type=1)

Comment: @identigral `Id` prefix is not relevant for the question, as there's no `Id` to work with at all.

Comment: Account.Id is an Id

Comment: @identigral `Account.Id` is a plain `String`. My question is, knowing where the relation starts at (e.g. an Opportunity), is it possible to dynamically determine what kind of an `SObject` "Account" substring might refer to. I don't have an Opportunity which has Account and Id selected, nor am I interested in it. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: You can, but I agree with this being an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Let's say this question was a User Story, I'd have to ask for more information before writing code that would definitively solve the requirements.

Comment: @sfdcfox You can what specifically? It's a simple and well-defined question. If there's no nicer way, I will accept a negative response. But to discount a question based on preconceptions of what should be asked is an inverse XY problem.

Comment: "Can I determine SObjectType Foo is referring to...?" is the question to which I responded "You can, but..." It'd be nice to know why you want to do this, the purpose behind it. Maybe there's a better way, maybe not. Seeing your other comments did help with context, but ideally, the question should be specific enough to say what you're doing, precisely how you're stuck, etc. I have several ideas in mind, but I'd like to know what you're trying to do for context.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm trying to determine the `SObjectType` of a relationship name portion of a full relationship given the starting `SObjectType`, which I tried to describe in the question. It's as specific as it gets. I'm interested in the inverse of reading a field via `get` and `getSObject`, i.e. writing via `put` and `putSObject`, in situations when the structure does not exist yet but would be dynamically created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the field you want to examine at compile-time, then you can get the describe information for that field directly.

`Opportunity.AccountId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()[0].getDescribe().getName()`

If this is more dynamic, and you don't know which field to examine until run-time, then there's no way around needing to get the field map from the `DescribeSObjectResult`, though since you can get a `Map<String, DescribeFieldResult>` (the keys are API names) you can simply get the specific field you're looking for.

`Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('AccountId').getDescribe().getReferenceTo()[0].getDescribe().getName())`

If you have an instance of an SObject with the target relationship field populated, you can use that Id to get at the SObject type

`myOpp.AccountId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName()`

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation! Unfortunately, general relations do not contain field names, but relationship names.

Comment: @ipavlic I think this is where we come to identigral and sfdcfox's request for more information. Knowing the scenario you're trying to apply this situation to would be helpful. Probably the most helpful clarification would be "how are you getting the "Account.Id" string?" and "can you pass different/additional information?". If you could pass "AccountId" instead of "Account.Id", that'd make your life easier (or at least free you of the burden of that loop you want to avoid).

Comment: It's the inverse of reading fields. Given a relation and an `SObject` instance, we can read the fields through `getSObject` and `get`. To write a field, we can use `put` and `putSObject`. However, if intermediate objects do not exist, I'd like to create them. It's all related to https://www.apexfp.org/ for which I'm writing a mapping function factory.